# Detect when image fails to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery I need to invoke a function when an image is missing. I need to use jquery as I am match all images that contain a certain path. doing this in jquery is simpler.

I found an example online but cannot establish why it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
// tried this and didn't work
$(document).on('error', 'img[src*="/image/path/"]', function() {
  alert('error loading image ' + $(this).attr('src'));
});

// to rule out path condition i tried this and it also didn't work
$('body').on('error', 'img', function() {
  alert('error loading image ' + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="/my/image/path/foo/bar.jpg" />
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vzxs6dq/4/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/92819/2630817

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of your issue is because the `error` event does not bubble, hence the delegated event handler you're attempting to use will not pick up the event from the `document`.

To fix this you'll need to use a static event handler defined directly on the `img` elements:

```js
$('img[src*="/image/path/"]').on('error', function() {
  console.log('error loading image ' + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="/my/image/path/foo/bar.jpg" />
```

If you have any `img` elements which are dynamically appended to the DOM after the page loads you will need to manually bind this event handler to them at the point they are created.

Comment: You could be clever and monitor the DOM for IMG tags being appended and ensure the event handler is added then (MutationObserver on body element)

Comment: That's true, if you felt the need to go that far.

Comment: Thanks, but this would fail on dynamic images wouldn't it?

Comment: That's correct, as my last comment points out and gives a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, based on your fiddle:

```
$('img[src*="/image/path/"]').on('error', function() {
  alert('error loading image ' + $(this).attr('src'));
});
```